# WebdriverIO - OR logical operator in selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, webdriver-io

I am using [Webdriver IO](https://webdriver.io/) in my project. I have the following code:

```
<div>
   <section id="my-section">
      {oneVariable && <p>enumVal1</p>}
      {someVariable && <p>enumVal2</p>}
      {anotherVariable && <a href="someSite">{anotherVariable}</a>}
   </section>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way through WebdriverIO, to check whether either of the enums (`enumVal1` or `enumVal2`) exist?

I've tried the following but this doesn't work:

```
$('#my-section').$('p*=enumVal1, p*=enumVal2').isExisting()
```

Problem is this selector is not treating these values with the OR operator. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like webdriverIOs element locators don't allow the partial link text selector (*=) with the css OR condition (,).
You could achieve this using xpath but it is a little messier.

```
$('#my-section').$(//p[text()="enumVal1"] | p[text()="enumVal2"]);
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thank you!